# Where do I put hook_js_alter code in Drupal 6 in order to use jQuery 1.8

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-6

One of my company's websites is using Drupal 6. I'm attempting to us hook_js_alter (from the jsalter module) to use jQuery 1.8.3 on the front-end rather than what Drupal is currently using (1.3.2).

I'm very new to Drupal (background is in WordPress), so things like this that might be obvious to experienced Drupal developers aren't to me.

I've already installed the module in the admin.

This is the code I'm using based on other stuff floating around google:

```
<?php
    function hook_js_alter(&$js) {
        if (isset($js['misc/jquery.js'])) {
            $jsPath = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js';
            $js['misc/jquery.js']['data'] = $jsPath;
            $js['misc/jquery.js']['version'] = '1.8.3';
        }
    }
?>
```

Where do I put this code? I've tried placing it in the header of my template (before the `<?=$scripts?>` tag) but it's not working there. Is this code even right?

I'm having a difficult time finding the instructions necessary to accomplish this with Drupal 6 so links to documentation or a tutorial would be really helpful.

**EDIT: Just realized there is Drupal Stack Exchange. This question should probably be migrated there.**

Comment: You should put it in your custom module. Please refer to http://api.drupal.org for more details. You need to change 'hook' in hook_js_alter to the module file name as well!

Comment: So if I create a module called "New jQuery" (filename newjquery.module) with all the code above, then the function should be newjquery_js_alter...?  Thanks for the doc link. Looking at that now.

Comment: Yes and your module name should be newjquery as well!

Answer (score 0):

Hook_js_alter does not exist in drupal6.  This is a drupal7 hook only.  I would check out running jQuery in no conflict. You can see some documentation [here](https://drupal.org/node/1058168). I would suggest method #2 which uses no_conflict.

FYI there is a module called [jQuery_update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update), but this will only upgrade Drupal6 to jQuery version 1.3.X.

Comment: This module JS Alter https://drupal.org/project/jsalter is supposed to add the hook to Drupal 6 which is what I've been trying to use. Ideally I'd like to not use noConflict, but if I have to, I have to.